# AJAX data parse to Controller and return back

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Here is an AJAX call to the controller:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("getChat", "Chat")',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $("#data").html(data);
    },
    error:{                  
    }
});
```

In the controller code, I have a database query which returns multiple rows.

I want to return that variable back to JSON and print each row separately in AJAX and write that data in HTML.

Here is my Controller code

```
public ActionResult getChat()
{
    var p = (from v in DB.chats where v.chatuserID == id select new { v.status, v.message }).ToList();
    return Content(p.ToString());
}
```

The query is returning data. I am attaching an image that shows the variables content.

[image: Image of return data of query]

Comment: You need to define the return type of data, in ajax you can use dataType:'json'   and return from controller json..

Comment: return json(p , json----------allow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public JsonResult getChat()
{
   var p = (from v in DB.chats 
            where v.chatuserID == id select new { v.status, 
            v.message 
            }).ToList();

    return json(p,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now you can loop through the list in you ajax success callback function : here is stuff.

```
$.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: '@Url.Action("getChat", "Chat")',
             success: function (data) {
             $.each(data,function(){
             console.log("Status "+ data.status +" "+"Message"+ data.message);
             });
             },
             error:{                  
             }
   });
```

Comment: Status undefined:Messageundefined

Comment: are you getting the responce in data variable??

Comment: yes, it goes in success function and i have written what it shows in console.

Comment: $.each(data,function(key,value){
             console.log("Status "+ value["status"] +" "+"Message"+ value["message"]);
             });